# How to send SOL with a solana rust contract

Tags: rust, blockchain, smartcontracts, solana

I'm a noob Rust/Solana Developer and feel like I'm encountering an issue that would be helpful to most other noobs.

I want to how to transfer SOL from an account to a program during an instruction, and then be able to send SOL back to the account who called the instruction.

I read the https://docs.solana.com/ but I could not find anything about SOL transfers via programs.

Example:

Acc1 calls the gamble instruction in Program1, which transfers 1 SOL from the caller and then runs a verifiable random function. If Acct1 wins the gamble, Program1 then sends 2 SOL back to Acct1.

I would really appreciate some help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a program similar to this one in the cookbook: https://solanacookbook.com/references/programs.html#how-to-do-cross-program-invocation

The differences in your case are to:

- use `solana_program::system_instruction::transfer` instead of `spl_token::instruction::transfer`
- only have source and destination accounts, without the owner
- sign with the source account
- pass in the system program instead of the token program

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm trying to build a program with your instructions but am running into the error ```An account required by the instruction is missing```

```let ix = solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(&pda, &user_address, 10000);
    invoke_signed(
        &ix,
        &[
            base_account.to_account_info().clone(),
            user.to_account_info().clone(),
            system_program.to_account_info().clone(),
        ],
        &[&[b"test", &[bump_seed]]],
    // solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(&pda, &user_address, 10000);
    );
    Ok(())```

Comment: `pda` and `base_account.key` need to be the same for the transfer to work.  Most likely they aren't the same account, so you'll need to pass in the pda to the insttruction.

Comment: got it! here is the github link if that gives you more context.
https://github.com/mark-antony1/7dice/blob/master/programs/dice/src/lib.rs

how can I derive the account info from the pda? The pda is just the address, right?

Comment: You have to derive the address off-chain, and then pass it in to your instruction, even though it doesn't exist yet.  Take a look at this example: https://solanacookbook.com/references/accounts.html#sign-with-a-pda

Comment: got it, thank you for the help!

Comment: Hi Jon! How do i add the type for the PDA as I define context for my method?

`#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SendLamports<'info> {
  #[account(init, payer = user, space = 9000)]
  pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,
  #[account(mut)]
  pub user: Signer<'info>,
  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
  pub pda: Account<'info>,
}`

is the general context I am trying to use so I can provide a pda as a string in the client, but that does not seem to be working

`error: bracket arguments must be the lifetime and type
60 |   pub pda: Account<'info>`

any ideas?