# Smart Contract for sending Solana Coin(Sol) from one wallet to another wallet

Tags: send, solana

I'm going to create a smart contract to send Sol from one wallet to another wallet on Solana.
I'm using Phantom wallet.

How to implement the above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687744/how-to-send-sol-with-a-solana-rust-contract/70690424

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send SOL with a solana rust contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687744/how-to-send-sol-with-a-solana-rust-contract)

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer sol directly from the client application(basically ts) or you can create a contract to do so via Cross Program Invocation

Export keypair from your Phantom wallet(and store it in a safe place or use a dummy) and use it to sign the transaction.

For Cross Program Invocation -
use `invoke()` to call the system program-

```
    // Transfer from PAYER to PAYEE a specific amount:
invoke(
    &system_instruction::transfer(payer.key, payee.key, amount),
    &[payer.clone(), payee.clone()],
)?;
```

Check out [Solana Bytes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDiEv2a7VC0&list=PLilwLeBwGuK51Ji870apdb88dnBr1Xqhm&index=10) and its Github.