# Send sol with rust

Tags: rust, solana

I'm trying to send sol from one wallet to another with rust.
I've tried to google it, asked on the solana-tech discord, followed the solana cookbook and the following thread:
[thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687744/how-to-send-sol-with-a-solana-rust-contract)

but I'm having a hard time to understand if what I'm doing is right.
our frontend developer is trying to implement my program without any success.
I've tried to test my program with cargo test and everything seems ok.
I'm attaching the code.
this is maybe a newbie question, but I'm sure it'll help many people.

```
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    msg,
    program::invoke,
    program_error::ProgramError,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    system_instruction::*,
};

entrypoint!(transfer_service_fee_lamports);

fn transfer_service_fee_lamports(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let from_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let to_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

    let amount = instruction_data
        .get(..8)
        .and_then(|slice| slice.try_into().ok())
        .map(u64::from_le_bytes)
        .ok_or(ProgramError::InvalidAccountData)?;

    if from_account.lamports() < amount {
        return Err(ProgramError::InsufficientFunds);
    }

    msg!(
        "Transferring {} tokens from {} to {}",
        amount,
        from_account.key.to_string(),
        to_account.key.to_string(),
    );
    let lamport_transfer = transfer(from_account.key, to_account.key, amount);

    let required_accounts_for_transfer = [from_account.clone(), to_account.clone()];

    invoke(&lamport_transfer, &required_accounts_for_transfer)?;

    msg!("transfer successful");
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: the problem was on the client side.|
the program works.
solved.

Comment: Could you add the answer to the answers section? It could help others in the future

Comment: The phantom wallet swallowed the error output and gave the error:  RPC Error: Transaction creation failed. We downloaded sol flare instead and got the error:Transaction simulation failed: error processing insurction 0: Invalid account data for instruction. Our frontend dev changed the passing data to the contract using the library solana buffer-layout